# Hibernate not inserting to mysql: showing insert statements

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, junit, transactions

I am doing a projecy using spring and hibernate. Hibernate showing "insert sql" statements, But the table is empty. I checked similar questions in the stackoverflow. But i couldnt find any questions similar to my problem.

// these are my entity classes

//Song Class

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name="Song", catalog="myFavMusic")
    public class Song implements Serializable {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
        private Integer id;

        public Song(){

        }
        public Song(String title, Album album, Singer singer, Integer rating) {
            super();
            Title = title;
            this.album = album;
             this.singer = singer;
             this.rating = rating;
        }

        private String Title;

        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        @JoinColumn(name = "ALBUM_ID", nullable = false)
        private Album album;

        @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        @JoinColumn(name = "SINGER_ID", nullable = false)
        private Singer singer;

        private Integer rating;
    }
```

// Album

```
    @Entity
    public class Album {    
        public Album(String title, String type, Integer releasedYear) {
            super();
            this.title = title;
            this.type = type;
            this.releasedYear = releasedYear;
        }

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        @Column(name = "ALBUM_ID", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 20)
        private Integer id;

        @Column(name = "TITLE", unique = true, nullable = false)
        private String title;

        @Column(name = "TYPE", unique = true, nullable = false)
        private String type;

        @Column(name = "RELEASED_YEAR", unique = true, nullable = false)
        private Integer releasedYear;
    }
```

// Singer Class

```
    @Entity
    public class Singer {

        public Singer(String singerName, Date dob) {
           super();
           this.singerName = singerName;
           this.dob = dob;
        }

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        @Column(name = "SINGER_ID", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 20)
        private Integer id;
        private String singerName;
        private Date dob;
   }
```

// This is my DAO Interface

```
   public interface MusicDao {
           public void addSong(Song song);
       public List<Song> listAllSongsBySpec(SongSpec spec);
   }
```

// This is my DAO Implementation

```
    public class MusicDaoImpl implements MusicDao {

        @Autowired
        private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

        public void addSong(Song song) {
            sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(song);
        }
    }
```

// Spring configuration

```
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource"><ref bean="dataSource" /></property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
           <props>
                   <prop  key="hibernate.dialect">  org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
                    </prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.myprojects.myfavmusic.domain" />
</bean>
<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
</bean>
<bean class=
            "org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location">
        <value>file:src/test/resources/config/database-unitFav.properties
        </value>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="musicDao" class="com.myprojects.myfavmusic.dao.impl.MusicDaoImpl"
    autowire="byName">
</bean>
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></property>
</bean>
```

// My Unit test to test this

```
    @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
    @ContextConfiguration(locations={"file:src/test/ApplicationContext- unitFav.xml"})
    public class MusicDaoImplTest extends TestCase {

        @Autowired
        private MusicDao musicDao;
        @Test
        @Transactional
        public void testAddSong() {
            Album album = new Album("album1","movie",2009);
            Singer singer = new Singer("singer 1",new Date());
            Song song = new Song("song 1",album,singer,0);
            musicDao.addSong(song);
            assertTrue(true);
       }
```

}

This seems to be a weird issue for me. Hibernate does not complain with any errors. But when i checked the DB there are no records. I thought this could be an issue with flushing modes. But I believe that the default Flushing mode is auto. Anyways i tried to specify the Flushing mode as well. But still the problem exists. Please help me on this?

Thanks In Advance,
Arun

Comment: You may be missing some instructions to tell hibernate to commit the results, could be? Check out if you need to issue sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().commit() or something like that.

Comment: I did that, but it did not work

Comment: Shift the @Transactional to your DAO.

Comment: it worked Alan Hay , how did it fixed the problem :)

Comment: Because your Test class is not a Spring managed bean and therefore the @Transactional declaration had no effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually this is the behavior I would expect (nothing to be there after the end of the test).

When you mark a test method with `@Transactional` at the end of the test all changes made in that method will be automatically rolled back. (As explained [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html#testing-tx) in the reference guide.

When you move your `@Transactional` to your dao instead of the test case, the test is no longer transactional and the data will remain. I wouldn't use this as a best practice as for starters it isn't your dao that should be transactional but your service layer. Next to that you don't want data from one test to interfere with another.

You should really be testing the existence of the data inside your test method (and not by using a sql browser or something alike.)

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"file:src/test/ApplicationContext- unitFav.xml"})
public class MusicDaoImplTest extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests {

    @Autowired
    private MusicDao musicDao;

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sf;

    @Test
    public void testAddSong() {
        Album album = new Album("album1","movie",2009);
        Singer singer = new Singer("singer 1",new Date());
        Song song = new Song("song 1",album,singer,0);
        musicDao.addSong(song);
        sf.getCurrentSession().flush(); // Similate a flush at the end of a transaction
        int count = countRowsInTable("song"); // Data should be in the table
        assertEquals(1, count);
   }
```

Something like that.

Final note your testcase is also slightly flawed you are mixing JUnit3 and JUnit4 types. You are extending `TestCase` which is JUnit3, whereas you are using a `@Test` annotation on the method to test. This is trouble (strange test results, execution etc.) waiting to happen.